# How to use multiple function/formula on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new using VBA and I'm trying to code into VBA but it didn't work so far, my timestamp data is not common and I got 10000+ rows to do the same formula (sometime excel just crash so i would like to try VBA)

timestamp that I tried split

[image]

[image]

Edit : add code

```
Sub Split_text_3()
        Dim p As String
        For x = 1 To 6 '---How do it until last cell?
            Cells(x, 2).Value = Mid(Cells(x, 1).Value, 9, 2) 'combind in same cell
            Cells(x, 3).Value = Mid(Cells(x, 1).Value, 5, 3) 'combind in same cell
            Cells(x, 4).Value = Mid(Cells(x, 1).Value, 21, 4) 'combind in same cell
            Cells(x, 5).Value = Mid(Cells(x, 1).Value, 12, 8) 
    Next x End Sub
```

and the data look like this (I tried to separate it first and then might try to combine them later)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GR4G.png)

Comment: convert your data to string in vba, use msgbox to see what value do you have, and after that use right, left, mid functions to extract date units.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Please include the code you have tried. We can only help you to fix the code if we can see it. • Also note that VBA might even be slower that formulas.

Comment: okay, let me post it  and see where I'm stuck

Comment: Are those dates in the left column numeric dates or text/string?

Comment: its text in all column, in order to do this properly where do I start with the data in left cell?

Comment: As others have mentioned, start putting together your own code and let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function extractDateTime(strTime As String) As Variant
   Dim arrD, d As Date, t As Date
   arrD = Split(strTime, " ")
   d = CDate(arrD(2) & "/" & arrD(1) & "/" & arrD(4))
   t = CDate(arrD(3))
   extractDateTime = Array(d, t)
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testExtractDate()
  Dim x As String, arrDate
  x = "WED SEP 08 08:13:52 2021"
  arrDate = extractDateTime(x)
  Debug.Print arrDate(0), arrDate(1)
End Sub
```

If it returns as you need (I think, yes...), you can use the next function to process the range. It assumes that the column keeping the strings are A:A, and returns in C:D:

```
Sub useFunction()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, Arr, arrDate, arrFin, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   Arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value
   If IsArray(Arr) Then
        ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(Arr), 1 To 2)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
             If Arr(i, 1) <> "" Then
                 arrDate = extractDateTime(CStr(Arr(i, 1)))
                 arrFin(i, 1) = arrDate(0): arrFin(i, 2) = arrDate(1)
             End If
        Next i
        sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin
   Else
        sh.Range("C2:D2").Value = extractDateTime(CStr(sh.Range("A2").Value))
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use on my sheet (might take some times.)

Comment: I got some problem with 1 row data on excel (other rows got delete by other module due to unnecessary)  `ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2)`  eg. only A2 have `WED MAR 24 05:22:22 202` Is there anyway to make it work with 1 line as well?

Comment: @alpha I am not sure I understand what you want... Do you mean that only a row to be processed remained  and the code returns an error? If so, is it the second row? If yes, I can adapt the code to deal with this situation, too, but I need your confirmation that my supposition/understanding is correct...

Comment: yes 'only a row to be processed remained and the code returns an error'

Comment: @alpha And this "one row" is the second one... I will adapt the code.

Comment: @alpha Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: @FaneDueu upload and tested, got error on function above 'extractDateTime' on `d = CDate(arrD(2) & "/" & arrD(1) & "/" & arrD(4))` *please see picture on my question

Comment: If your string looks as you posted it here (`WED MAR 24 05:22:22 202`, VBA is not able to deal with 202 year, I am afraid...

Comment: It's fixed now, Thanks @FaneDuru. The problem actually on `sh.Range("C2:D2").Value = extractDateTime(CStr(sh.Range("A2").Value))` I did not change A2 to B2 which I use on my sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have another solution (not bulletproof) but it is simplier, quicker and code less solution (no offense FraneDuru!):

```
Sub DateStamp()
    Dim arr, arr_temp, arr_new() As Variant
    Dim i As long
    
    'Take cells from selected all the way down to 1st blank cell
    'and assign values to an array
    arr = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Value
    
    ReDim Preserve arr_new(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        'Make another array by spliting input string by whitespace delimiter (default)
        arr_temp = Split(arr(i, 1))
        
        'Construct values in desired "format"
        arr_new(i, 1) = "'" & arr_temp(2) & "/" & arr_temp(1) & "/" & arr_temp(4)
        arr_new(i, 2) = arr_temp(3)
    Next i
    
    'Paste result into Excel
     Selection.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(arr), 2) = arr_new
End Sub
```

All you have to do is to select the cell toy want to start with and run the macro! :)
[image]

Bellow also a picture with watches, so you can catch-up what is going on:
[image]

Comment: It cannot be faster. And using so many 'Redim Preserve' is a bad memory handling way. Selection is enen a worst way, which only consumes excel resources and does not bring any benefit... Did you test the code. You can Redim Preserve oly the last array dimension.

Comment: And using redim preserve for the same number of elements is completelly uselesd, except the memory stress...

Comment: You should declare `i` as `Long` too since it can potentially end up with a number bigger than what`Integer` can hold thus causing overflow

Comment: I agree with your comments, edited. Redim only once. @FaneDuru, FYI your code works if your system language is english, otherwise it throws "Type mismatch" error when executing line: `d = CDate(arrD(2) & "/" & arrD(1) & "/" & arrD(4))`
Execution time for 1048576 rows (max Excel can handle) is around 6,285 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @kamikadze366 for the explanation.

Comment: I know that it can raise an error. Since the big majority uses English OS, I offered such a solution. I can build a different one and I should do it if OP should complain about it, using `DateSerial` and an matching the months in an array keeping the three digits months abbreviation. Your code does not return a date in any case, if it raises such an error. It returns a string and the request, at least in my understanding was to transform the existing string format in data in `Date`.